# Get user visits count of window in appcelerator titanium

Tags: ios, count, appcelerator

I am working on ios app,,User will login to the app.I have multiple screens in one screen i have a requirement is if user first time visits that screen i need to show the instructions screen.If screen visits count more than once no need to show the instructions.

```
I need to store that screens count for each user separately how can we achieve this in appcelerator titanium
```

Please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **open** or **focus** event to pick up when someone hits the screen and then either:

1. If this is a connected app, and you're downloading the user profile on login, you could store a flag to say tutorialSeen or similar. Check this when the window opens / focuses or
2. if not connected or you want to store locally, store the flag in the Ti.App.Properties under a user profile.

(you could equally store a count value that increments when they hit the screen but since you just want the first time captured, I'd go with a) capture event, b) check property, c) if false, set to true and show tutorial, d) if true, skip.)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not need to store the user visit count if your only purpose is to show the Instruction window only when user login into the app for first time.

You can do it this way:

***someController.js***

```
function onLoginSuccess() {
    // getInt() will return the value of INSTRUCTION_WINDOW property, you can name this property whatever you want. 
    // if this property does not exist, then it will return the value of the second parameter.
    var showInstruction = Ti.App.Properties.getInt("INSTRUCTION_WINDOW", 1);

    if (showInstruction) {
        Alloy.createController('instructionWindow').getView().open();   

    } else {
        Alloy.createController('nextWindow').getView().open();  
    }
}


// logout function can be anywhere
// remember to set the property to 1 if you want to show the instructions again after logout and then login.
function logout() {
    Ti.App.Properties.setInt("INSTRUCTION_WINDOW", 1);
}
```

***instructionWindow.js***

```
$.instructionWindow.addEventListener('open', function () {
    // after opening the instruction window, set this property to 0
    // so it won't be shown up the next time the already logged-in user opens the app
    Ti.App.Properties.setInt("INSTRUCTION_WINDOW", 0);
});
```

Comment: HI Prashant saini, Thanks for giving reply.How can we handle multiple users will login to the app.it will not showing the instructions screen if user is visit first time for that screen, if previous user is already visits that page.

Comment: If you really want to show the Help Screen to all users who visits first time on app, then you will need to save the login count in database and fetch it in login web-service and then you can easily know that user is using the app for first time.

But most of the app only concerns to show Help screen only first time the app is opened on device no matter who the user is.

Answer (score 0):

> first you set the nsuserdefaults value @"1".

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"1" forKey:@"showtheinstruction"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

> after this you have to compare this string and shows the instruction message.

```
NSString *str_savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
stringForKey:@"showtheinstruction"];

if (str_savedValue isEqualToString:@"1") {

// show the instruction window.
 }
else
{
// don't show the instruction window.
}
```